# Catch error text in custom 500 handler

Tags: django

Somewhere in my views, I throw an error, particularly this one:

**views.py**

```
from xmlrpclib import Fault

def some_function(request):
    if ....:
        return Fault(-1, 'foo')
```

Then, also in **views.py**, I have my custom 500 handler to catch server errors:

```
def my_custom_500(request):
    context = {...}
    ### Here is where I need to catch `'foo'` 
    ### in order to put it in the context and pass it to the template
    render(request, '500.html', context)
```

Is there anyway in which I can access the error message?
Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try to override `django.conf.urls.defaults.handler500` in your `urls.py`.

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
handler500 = 'path.to.my_custom_500'
```

or even better - write your own handler and put it in the [`LOGGING` settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/#examples).

**Edit**:

You can also add to your `my_custom_500` code that will recognize type of exception, eg:

```
import sys; 

def my_custom_500(request):
    ...
    type_, value, traceback = sys.exc_info()
    ...
```

Comment: This wasn't my question. I already did this override. What I need is to access the error message that triggered the custom 500.

Comment: Add to your `my_custom_500` function: `import sys; type, value, traceback = sys.exc_info()` and check what you [will get](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info).

Comment: yep, I've just found the exact same solution somewhere... post it as an answer so I can vote it up