# How to pass exception to 500 error handler in Django

Tags: python, django, http, error-handling

I have been learning Django and experimenting with custom error pages. However, to display these pages you have to set DEBUG = False in the settings which in turn prevents any information about server errors being displayed. Therefore, I wanted to setup a custom 500 handler that will display the exception that is raised.

I setup the following error handlers:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse

def handler404(request, exception):
    # make a redirect to homepage
    return redirect('cookiecrumbsapp/cookieCrumbs')

def handler500(request):
    #handle error messages for debugging - set to obscure error once tested
    return HttpResponse("500")
```

And added the appropriate definitions in my urls file:

```
handler404 = 'cookiecrumbs.views.handler404'
handler500 = 'cookiecrumbs.views.handler500'
```

These handlers work fine, but I cannot find a way of displaying the actual exception/error that causes a 500 error on the server. I know that in older versions of Django (<2.2 according to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55481810/django-2-2-breaks-previously-working-views-urls)) they had functionality for passing an `exception` parameter to the 500 handler, just like the 404 one, but that this was removed - is there any way to achieve similar functionality in new versions so that I can display error messages on my page?

Django version is 2.2.7 if that helps

**EDIT:** [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24511092/catch-error-text-in-custom-500-handler/24511217#24511217) provided a great solution

Comment: Is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24511217/6525260) helpful?

Comment: Yes that worked perfectly, thank you