# Django catch missing manifest exceptions

Tags: django

Every now and then I end up with a missing file after deploy a django project, and I find it one of the hardest issues to debug because I get no logging and no error email, its just dead. I have made a custom 500 error page ([followed this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24511092/catch-error-text-in-custom-500-handler/24511217#24511217)). Is it possible to show the details of which static file is missing on it? With this error Django fails before rendering a 500 page.

Heres a traceback of the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 137, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/home/user/venv/project/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 133, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/home/user/venv/project/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 75, in get_response
    response = self._middleware_chain(request)
  File "/home/user/venv/project/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 36, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "/home/user/venv/project/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 90, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "/home/user/venv/project/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 129, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return callback(request, **param_dict)
  File "/home/user/project/src/core/base/views.py", line 236, in error_500_view
    response = render(request, "core.base/500.html", context=context)
  File "/home/user/venv/project/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "/home/user/venv/project/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "/home/user/venv/project/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/home/user/venv/project/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 171, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/home/user/venv/project/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 95, in instrumented_test_render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/user/venv/project/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/user/venv/project/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/user/venv/project/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/home/user/venv/project/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 95, in instrumented_test_render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/user/venv/project/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/user/venv/project/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/user/venv/project/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/templatetags/static.py", line 106, in render
    url = self.url(context)
  File "/home/user/venv/project/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/templatetags/static.py", line 103, in url
    return self.handle_simple(path)
  File "/home/user/venv/project/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/templatetags/static.py", line 118, in handle_simple
    return staticfiles_storage.url(path)
  File "/home/user/venv/project/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 153, in url
    return self._url(self.stored_name, name, force)
  File "/home/user/venv/project/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 132, in _url
    hashed_name = hashed_name_func(*args)
  File "/home/user/venv/project/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 423, in stored_name
    raise ValueError("Missing staticfiles manifest entry for '%s'" % clean_name)
ValueError: Missing staticfiles manifest entry for 'img/pwa/browserconfig.xml'
```